# Using ros common tutorials packages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a machine that has the common tutorials package being installed but I'm not sure where it is installed or how can I use those packages.

```
http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/common_tutorials?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22common_tutorials%22
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268976/using-ros-common-tutorials-packages/) by [ros_a](https://answers.ros.org/users/31009/ros_a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find the tutorials by using `rosbash` ([here's how to navigate the file system](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem#ROS.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-catkin.2BAC8-NavigatingTheFilesystem.Filesystem_Tools)). To find out if you have the `common_tutorials` simply run `roscd common_tutorials` and if you have it then this will take you to them (`/opt/ros/<distrobution>/share/common_tutorials`).

You'll find that, however, that package is empty except for the package.xml. So, as @2ROS0 pointed out, just go to `/opt/ros/<distrobution>/share/` and look for the actionlib_tutorials, nodelet_tutorial_math, pluginlib_tutorials, and turtle_actionlib folders. They have the actual tutorials.

To use them, just use them as you would any other package.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0